# How do I ignore properties when using RestSharp serialization

Tags: c#, rest, attributes, xamarin, restsharp

I was looking for something like this:

```
...
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }

[Ignore]
public string FullName { get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; } }
...
```

But, can't seem to dig anything up.

Environment: Xamarin Studio, C#, Android Project running on Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is dependant on which serializer you are using:

- For the [JsonSerializer](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serializers/JsonSerializer.cs), use `[ScriptIgnore]`.
- For the [DotNetXmlSerializer](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serializers/DotNetXmlSerializer.cs), use `[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]`.

I can't answer with certainty what attribute should be used when you use [XmlSerializer](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serializers/XmlSerializer.cs) but I would suspect it should be either `[NonSerialized]`, `[ScriptIgnore]` or `[XmlIgnore]`.

Documentation:

- [ScriptIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx).
- [NonSerialized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- [XmlIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).